# Using a resource's parameters to update a delay time

Tags: resources, delay, anylogic

I am working on simulating a simple put to light activity. A source generates an agent "package", then a resource "operator" is seized, moves the package to a destination node representing a tote, then there is a delay representing the processing of that package into the tote, then the operator goes back to its initial location and waits for another package.
I am trying to simulate the fact that as the operator gets tired, the processing of the packages takes longer. In my operator agent, I calculate a fatigue level according to the time spent used as a resource in the put to light activity.

However, I do not know how to access this fatigue level present in my "operator" from the Main page, where the operator is used as a resource. How can I use this fatigue level in the delay time of the package processing? Basically, in a process that seizes a resource, how do I use the resource variables/parameters in order to influence a delay time in that process?
If you have any examples/files that use resource parameters to set up a variable delay time, I would love to have a working example. I started using AnyLogic recently and cannot seem to figure this one out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom resource types](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/resource-type.html). Then in your resourcePool block, switch "New resource unit" to your new resource type. To compute fatigue, refer to the "Accessing parameters of custom resources" section of that same page. The way fatigue will concretely be modeled is up to you.

To access information contained within a resource that was seized, you can use `agent.resourceUnits()` documented [here](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/Agent.html#resourceUnits()), and use that to calculate your fatigued delay.

For example, in your "Delay time" field, assuming

- each agent only seizes a single resource
- a 15 second baseline time for processing
- a v_fatiguePenalty variable within your resource type that represents
  fatigue

you can input:

```
agent.resourceUnits().get(0).v_fatiguePenalty + 15
```